# Button made in one function does not exist in another in Tkinter and Python

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am having a massive problem with Tkinter and Python. I am a massive python noob and I really need to solve this problem. Anyway, the problem is buttons made in a function do not exist in another. I tried to solve it by using classes but that only broke my code. I do not know what to do. Please, please help me. Here is the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font

sudo = tk.Tk()

defaultbold = font.Font(weight="bold")
gothicbold = font.Font(family='Gothic',weight="bold")
opnfont = font.Font(family='Open Sans')

sudo.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

sudo.title('Macbeth Learning')

sudo.configure(bg='dark red')

sudo.iconphoto(True, tk.PhotoImage(file= "C:\\Users\\dance\\Desktop\\Programming\\Macbeth\\Python\\Source code\\0.0.4\\macbethicon.png"))

def opn():
    startlabl.place_forget()
    openbtn.place_forget()
    quizbtn = tk.Button(sudo, text="Quiz", bg="dark red",height=1, width=10)
    quizbtn['font'] = opnfont
    quizbtn.place(x=560, y=385)
    learnbtn = tk.Button(sudo, text="Learn", bg="dark red",height=1, width=10)
    learnbtn['font'] = opnfont
    learnbtn.place(x=670, y=385)
    readbtn = tk.Button(sudo, text="Read", bg="dark red", height=1, width=10)
    readbtn['font'] = opnfont
    readbtn.place(x=560, y=425)
    abtbtn = tk.Button(sudo, text="About", bg="dark red", height=1, width=10, command=about)
    abtbtn['font'] = opnfont
    abtbtn.place(x=670, y=425)

def about():
    quizbtn.place_forget()
    learnbtn.place_forget()
    readbtn.place_forget()
    abtbtn.place_forget()
                        


bgimage =tk.PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\dance\\Desktop\\Programming\\Macbeth\\Python\\Source code\\0.0.4\\af6817.png")
bgimagepl = tk.Label(sudo, image=bgimage)

bgimagepl.place(x=50, y=0)

openbtn = tk.Button(sudo, text="Start", bg="dark red",height=1, width=10, command = opn)
openbtn['font'] = opnfont
openbtn.place(x=567, y=385)
                    
extbuton = tk.Button(sudo, text="Exit", command=sudo.destroy, height=1, width=10, fg="white", bg="dark red")
extbuton['font'] =defaultbold
extbuton.place(x=1256, y=740)

startlabl = tk.Label(sudo, text="Welcome to Macbeth Learning, The ultimate experience to learn about Macbeth.",bg="dark red")
startlabl['font'] = gothicbold
startlabl.place(x=100, y=0)

manlabl = tk.Label(sudo, text="Macbeth Learning", bg="red")



sudo.mainloop()
```

Comment: see how to produce a [mcve] and [ask] a question

Comment: The simple fix is make them global by adding `global quizbtn, learnbtn, readbtn, abtbtn` at the beginning of `opn()`.